# select and return count of a particular value with results in SQL

Tags: sql, select, count, group-by, field

I want to select from a table and return the number of occurrences of a particular value in a column.

I also want the number of occurrences of that value to appear in the result set.

For example

With this Car table

```
type color 
===== ===
bmw   blue
lexus green
Ford  blue
KIA   yellow
```

I would like to build a query that will return the following results.

```
type  color   colorcount
===== ===     =======
bmw    blue    2
lexus  green   1
Ford   blue    2
KIA    yellow  1
```

I tried:

```
select type,color, count(color) from Car
```

but this obviously didn't work.  Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.type, c.color, x.colorCount
  FROM car c
      ,( SELECT color, COUNT(*) colorCount
           FROM car
           GROUP by color ) x
  WHERE c.color = x.color;
```